# NoSuchMethodError when running UIMA Ruta script from UIMAFIT SimplePipeline

Tags: uima, ruta

I am trying to run an existing UIMA Ruta analysis engine from a UIMAFIT simple pipeline using the following code:

```
File specFile = new File("MyEngine.xml");
XMLInputSource in = new XMLInputSource(specFile);
ResourceSpecifier specifier = UIMAFramework.getXMLParser().parseResourceSpecifier(in);
AnalysisEngineDescription aed = (AnalysisEngineDescription) specifier;
builder.add(aed); // Builder is an aggregateBuilder
```

Upon running it, it resolves imports from the engine's main script (the Cleartk Stanford tools) and then quits with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.uima.ruta.type.RutaBasic.setLowMemoryProfile(Z)V
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaStream.initalizeBasics(RutaStream.java:173)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:575)
at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:432)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:378)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:298)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:568)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:410)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:343)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.processUntilNextOutputCas(ASB_impl.java:568)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl$AggregateCasIterator.<init>(ASB_impl.java:410)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.process(ASB_impl.java:343)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:265)
at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:267)
at org.uimafit.pipeline.SimplePipeline.runPipeline(SimplePipeline.java:80)
at org.myproject.workflow.ParagraphAnnotationPipeline.main(ParagraphAnnotationPipeline.java:107)
```

The engine was created using a pre-release of Ruta 2.2.0 and the pipeline runs in UIMA 2.5.0 using UIMAFIT 2.0.0 and Ruta-core 2.1.0 imported using maven.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I set lowMemoryProfile to false in both my engine xml descriptor and the BasicEngine descriptor, which did not work. I did not try the rules form directly within java, but I'd rather not go that way as I will have a large Ruta project that plugs into the pipeline with various imports in it.

Comment: The actual value is not important because the method does not exist at all. The exception occurs when the engine tries to set the value independently of its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is most likely caused by the fact that the JCas classes are overwritten. UIMA Ruta provides a few JCas classes of the types defined for seeding, inference and additional analysis engines. One of them (at least, but most important) contains additional methods for storing information about annotations and more: RutaBasic. These JCas classes must not be overwritten.

There is a mention in the README for users that apply JCasGenPomFriendly:

```
If you use the uimaFIT JCasGenPomFriendly in Maven and want to use UIMA Ruta 
as a standalone annotator you have to exclude the generated UIMA Ruta basic 
type files from the build, e.g., by adding:

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <configuration>
     <excludes>
         <exclude>org/apache/uima/ruta/type/*.java</exclude>
     </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can you please check if you generated RutaBasic and if the class contains for example the method setLowMemoryProfile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure I know I understand it all. I added the exclusion to the pom files of both my pipeline project and the Ruta project, but the exception still occurred. How do I check if I generate Ruta basic? I checked the RutaBasic.class in the target folder, but I could not find a match for the memory method. But maybe that is not what you meant.

Comment: If you did not find the setLowMemoryProfile method, then that is a good indicator that the class was generated anew. Have you maybe imported the Ruta type system descriptors (BasicTypeSystem.xml or InternalTypeSystem) in one of your type system descriptors and then generated the JCas classes mabye using the Component Descriptor editor? The RutaBasic class should normally not occur in the target of your project, but the RutaBasic class of the dependency to ruta-core should be used.

Comment: In fact, I did something like this. In my Ruta project, I added some java code for an additional annotator for which I use an additional type system descriptor and JCasGen to auto-generate the descriptor files. I would rather not pull this into an external project because I only ever need these annotators in the Ruta context. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to delete at least the classes `RutaBasic.java` and `RutaBasic_Type.java`. Best delete the complete source folder `org.apache.uima.ruta.type`.

Comment: That did it! I deleted the complete source folder, then the system would not compile. I removed the exclusion form the pom file and ran JCasGen again from my custom type system descriptor. Then my script ran again and I can import it into my pipeline. Thanks a lot!